# Run scripts in parallel, one set after another splitting main file?

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a file, `abc.txt`, like this on a Linux machine:

```
abc|yes|50c|1|pending
bcd|no|100c|1|pending
cde|yes|45c|2|pending
def|no|44c|2|pending
```

I have split this file into two files based on the 4th field. `1.txt`:

```
abc|yes|50c|1|pending
bcd|no|100c|1|pending
```

And `2.txt`

```
cde|yes|45c|2|pending
def|no|44c|2|pending
```

If the second field is 'yes' I want to call a script with the 3rd field as a parameter, or if the second field is 'no' the 1st field as a parameter, and run the scripts in parallel. 1.txt should run, then 2.txt and if any script fails it should update the last field from pending to FAILED/SUCCESS.(my scripts passes 0-success,1-failed return code)

For example:

`1.txt`

```
ksh script1.ksh 50c
ksh script1.ksh bcd
```

`2.txt`

```
ksh script1.ksh 45c
ksh script1.ksh def
```

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your post. You can use code blocks for your file data. Also, please show us what you have so far so we don't need to reinvent what you have already solved.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

runksh() {
    ksh script1.sh "$1";
}
export -f runksh

doit() {
    parallel --joblog +my.log --colsep '\|' \
             runksh '{=1 $_ = $arg[2] eq "yes" ? $arg[3] : $arg[1] =}' {};
}
export -f doit

parallel -u --colsep '\|' -j1 --group-by 3 --pipepart -a abc.txt doit

# my.log now contains whether a job succeeded or failed
# Extract exit code + argument
awk -e '$7 != 0 { print $11"|"$12"|"$13"|"$14"|FAILED"; }' my.log > failed
awk -e '$7 == 0 { print $11"|"$12"|"$13"|"$14"|SUCCEEDED"; }' my.log > succeeded
cat failed succeeded
```